# How to implement a slider with range binded with the number input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, rc-slider

I am using antd slider component . I am trying to implement a range slider which is also binded with two number inputs like the image attached below

[image: sliderComponentImg]

Find my code in the given link https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-framework-xpvl9. On adding range props to the slider component it throws error. I am confused with the logic in implementing min and max in the number inputs binded with the range slider.

````
<Slider
          className="slider-main-div"
          min={min}
          max={max - 1}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={typeof inputValue === "number" ? inputValue : 0}
        />
        <div className="range-input-number-main">
          <InputNumber
            className="min-input-main"
            min={min + 1}
            max={max - 1}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.onChangeMin}
          />
          <span className="range-span">to</span>
          <InputNumber
            className="min-input-main"
            min={21}
            max={50}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.onChangeMax}
          />
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should be using separate variables to store your minimum and maximum value. Currently your slider value, input minimum value and input maximum value all point to the variable 'value'.. This will clash in your code. 
Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mcclintock-blm4e

Comment: But in some scenario it fails Select 49 in first input then the second input should not go below 50 . But its dropping below 49. There is no range in the slider . It works independently for one input number

Comment: If you want the second input to have a minimum that is linked to the value of the first input, you can use the code in the codesandbox (i updated mine)